# Sequence of parameters in Axis2 1.7.8

Tags: apache-axis

I am deploying a POJO as a service in axis 2 1.7.8 . Following is the method signature :

```
public String authenticate(String username, String password, String dName, String sName) 
{
    return authenticateWithRole(username, password, "", dName, sName);
}
```

I am skipping the wsdl generated part. Following is the Request SOAP as generated in SOAPUI :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:lab="test_authenticate">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <lab:authenticate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <lab:username>a</lab:username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <lab:password>b</lab:password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <lab:dName>c</lab:dName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <lab:sName>d</lab:sName>         
      </lab:authenticate>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The above SOAP works.  If the sequence of the parameters is changed, things do not work.  For example, if I send the 'sName' parameter as first parameters, the preceding parameter values are set to null :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:lab="test_authenticate">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <lab:authenticate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <lab:sName>d</lab:sName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <lab:username>a</lab:username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <lab:password>b</lab:password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <lab:dName>c</lab:dName>
         
      </lab:authenticate>
   </soap:Body>
</soap>
```

This means that the sequence of parameters matters in axis 2.

How do I change this so that the second SOAP also works and the client is not bound to send the parameters in fixed sequence.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the BeanUtils.deserialize of apache-adb library method. So if the parameters in are not sent in the order they are defined at the method level, parameters which are pushed back in the order are set to null.

Needs a code fix.